# Parsing only the IP addresses in a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have the following `/etc/hosts` file:

```
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
    ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
    ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

    ## vagrant-hostmanager-start
    10.60.63.6  dgnode-1 dgnode-1.dg.local
    10.144.64.75    dgnode-2 dgnode-2.dg.local
    10.226.98.24    namenode namenode.dg.local
    ## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

When I execute the following `awk` command I get:

```
awk 'NR==1{ips=$1} NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1} $2=="namenode"{nn=$1} END{
   printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -HS %s -N MyCluster\n",
          ips, nn, nn}' /etc/hosts
```

I'm getting:

```
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 127.0.0.1, , #, ::1, fe00::0, ff00::0, ff02::1, ff02::2, ff02::3, , ##, 10.60.63.6, 10.144.64.75, 10.226.98.24, ##, -Z 10.226.98.24 -HS 10.226.98.24 -N MyCluster
```

Instead of

```
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 10.60.63.6, 10.144.64.75, 10.226.98.24 -Z 10.226.98.24 -HS 10.226.98.24 -N MyCluster
```

Which is want I want. That's it, just the IP addresses, with the exception of `127.0.0.1`.How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should say that you are only seeking IPv4 addresses, since fe00::0 is a valid IPv6 address. I'm adding the top line:

```
egrep '^[0-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | \
    awk 'NR==1{ips=$1} NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1} $2=="namenode"{nn=$1} END{
    printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -HS %s -N MyCluster\n",
    ips, nn, nn}'
```

produces:

```
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 10.60.63.6, 10.144.64.75, 10.226.98.24 -Z 10.226.98.24 -HS 10.226.98.24 -N MyCluster
```

I don't know `mapr`, but most arguments-parsing libraries will be looking for *just* a comma, no comma-space, so you may need to change to `{ips=ips "," $i}` to produce:

```
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 10.60.63.6,10.144.64.75,10.226.98.24 -Z 10.226.98.24 -HS 10.226.98.24 -N MyCluster
```